# JPA Set of Set of Entity

Tags: java, jpa, collections, many-to-many

Is there a possibility to achieve a set of sets of some specific entity? If yes, how do I need to annotate that field? My java class looks the following:

```java
class Foo {
  long id;
  int value;
  Set<Set<Bar>> barSets;
}

class Bar {
  long id;
  String name;

  String toString() { return name; }
}
```

My database tables are specified as following:

```sql
CREATE TABLE foo (
  id LONG PRIMARY KEY,
  value INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE bar (
  id LONG PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE foo_bar (
  foo_id LONG REFERENCES foo,
  set_index INTEGER,
  bar_id LONG REFERENCES bar
);
```

The set_index of the foo_bar table defines which entries belong together within the same foo element. Maybe there is also some better approach to achieve this?

Example:

```
foo:
id | value
---|------
 1 | 100 
 2 | 200

bar:
id | name
---|------
 1 | AAA 
 2 | BBB
 3 | CCC

foo_bar:
foo_id | set_index | bar_id
-------|-----------|-------
     1 |         1 |      1
     1 |         1 |      2
     1 |         2 |      1
     1 |         2 |      3
     2 |         1 |      2
     2 |         1 |      3
```

Java objects:

- Foo { id=1, value=100, bars=[ [AAA, BBB], [AAA, CCC] ] }
- Foo { id=2, value=200, bars=[ [BBB, CCC] ] }

Comment: My suggestion is to separate the code used for persistence from the code used for business logic. So, persistence code has 3 entity classes, one for each table. The mappings are straightforward. Your DAO layer translates the entity objects to domain model objects, having e.g. the `Set<Set<Bar>>` property. This involves writing more code, but results in a cleaner, more maintainable system by applying separation of concerns. Besides that, I don't think this mapping is possible with JPA. Perhaps you could trick JPA with an embeddable that implements `Set`???